# When doing transaction my total issuance got deducted

Tags: balances, transaction-fees

I am currently working on incorporating a transaction fee logic where the block reward for a validator is intended to be shared between the validator and its nominator. However, I am encountering an issue where the fees for the nominator are being deducted from the total issuance.

Comment: I didn't get why "the fees for the nominator are being deducted from the total issuance"

Comment: Suppose the transaction fees allocated to the validator amount to 24 units. My implementation ensures an equitable distribution, splitting the fees evenly between the validator and their nominators. With a total fee of 24, the validator receives 12, while the remaining 12 is allocated to the nominators. Although the distribution to the nominators works as intended, an issue arises where the total issuance is also deducted by 12

Comment: I don't think so, the total issuance is guaranteed by the Rust drop mechanism. Could you share your code then I can take a look at how did you implement that?